# How to $inc mutil value with update in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

i have

- products
- days

two collections for now

the data what i try to update sort of like

```
{
    _id: "85a2c512-e670-4bac-a024-c46768e91839"
    day: "2013-01-10"
    id: "E666A9erpx"
    month: "2013-01"
    products: [
        {
            amount: 0
            id: "LRRRBKRgBj"
            price: 2
        },
        {
            amount: 0
            id: "qeeeXGe5G7"
            price: 8.9
        }
    ]
    year: "2013"
}
```

i want to $inc these value

```
db.products.update(
  { id: E666A9erpx, 'products.id': [ LRRRBKRgBj, qeeeXGe5G7  ]  } ,
  { $inc: { 'products.$.amount': [ 200, 104 ] } }
)
```

how do i $inc ?

Comment: Heh this is actually a gotcha in MongoDB, it does only operate on the first found positional operator. I *think* (I might be wrong) but the best way atm is to do this client side

Comment: If you want to operate on multiple products in this situation, it's definitely better to construct a schema where different products are separate documents.  Having them all embedded in an array limits your ability to manipulate multiple elements unless you know their index position.

Comment: i want to record every products of daily sales. yes i have products in separate collection and i have a day collection to log every day's summary.